# How to listen for multicast messages in java?

Tags: java, network-programming, broadcast

I was doing the oracle's tutorial about Broadcasting to multiple recipients but I am getting an error for the client side.
As the oracle's example states, I have my client code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(4446);
    InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("203.0.113.0");
    socket.joinGroup(group);

    DatagramPacket packet;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        socket.receive(packet);

        String received = new String(packet.getData());
        System.out.println("Quote of the Moment: " + received);
    }

    socket.leaveGroup(group);
    socket.close();
}
```

Which throws an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Not a multicast address
    at java.net.MulticastSocket.joinGroup(MulticastSocket.java:310)
    at BroadcastListener.main(BroadcastListener.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Multicast IP address must start with 224.., as per RFC 5771.

From wikipedia:

> IPv4 multicast addresses are defined by the leading address bits of
>   1110, originating from the classful network design of the early
>   Internet when this group of addresses was designated as Class D. The
>   Classless Inter-Domain Routing (CIDR) prefix of this group is
>   224.0.0.0/4.

Comment: well, so what address should i use? if i use for example 224.0.113.0 it throws an exception saying "Can't assign requested address"